Error with id_token_hint with Client-Initiated Logout in my oauth2 Client after I refresh my access_token
Let me explain my use case.
I have a problem with my BFF(Backend for Frontend) implementation which is mainly in the logout, as my 10 minutes duration access_token is refreshed before it expires by a call I make from angular. I have an api called /authenticate that makes a call to the authorization-server and this makes the token refresh but I have the problem that after doing this and I want to logout I get an error that the id_token_hint is wrong, this is solved if I go back in the page to return to the client because it makes a reload and redo the authorization flow and just in this case the logout works but not when I do the refresh with this:
This is my config for my Authorization-Server:
application.yml:
logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
    org:
      springframework:
        security: DEBUG
        session: DEBUG
        web: DEBUG
spring:
  mvc:
    problemdetails:
      enabled: true
  application:
    name: bo-oauth-server
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  config:
    import: optional:configserver:${CONFIG_SERVER_URL}

intechbo:
  server:
    gateway: ${GATEWAY_SERVER_PORT}
    oauth: ${OAUTH_SERVER_PORT}
  oauth:
    issuer: ${OAUTH_SERVER_ISSUER}
server:
  servlet:
    session:
      timeout: 720m
      cookie:
        max-age: 720m

This is my security config from Authorization-Server:
@Configuration
@Slf4j
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AuthorizationSecurityConfig {

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    private final AccessTokenAuthenticationFilter filter;

    @Value("${intechbo.server.gateway}")
    String gatewayServerPort;
    @Value("${intechbo.server.oauth}")
    String oauthServerPort;

    public AuthorizationSecurityConfig(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, AccessTokenAuthenticationFilter filter) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.filter = filter;
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "PUT", "PATCH"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("X-Requested-With", "Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Authorization"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin(gatewayServerPort);
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin(oauthServerPort);
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:4200");
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("http://127.0.0.1:4200");
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("http://gateway-dev.inclub:8090");
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("http://webapp-dev.inclub:4200");
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {

        http
                .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()));

        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
                .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());    // Enable OpenID Connect 1.0
        http
                // Redirect to the login page when not authenticated from the authorization endpoint
                .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
                        .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                                new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"),
                                new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                        )
                )
                // Accept access tokens for User Info and/or Client Registration
                .oauth2ResourceServer(
                        (resourceServer) -> resourceServer.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults())
                );
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(
            HttpSecurity http
    ) throws Exception {

        http
                .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("styles.css", "styles.css.map", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**", "/webjars/**", "/favicon.ico").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/login", "/error", "/logged-out").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .addFilterAfter((Filter) filter, (Class<? extends Filter>) UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .formLogin(
                        formLogin -> formLogin
                                .loginPage("/login")
                                .permitAll()
                )
                .sessionManagement(
                        sessionManagement -> sessionManagement
                                .invalidSessionUrl(gatewayServerPort + "/backoffice/home")
                );
//                .logout(logout -> logout
//                        .logoutSuccessUrl(gatewayServerPort + "/logged-out")
//                        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
//                );

        return http.build();

    }

    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        RegisteredClient oidcClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID()
                        .toString())
                .clientId("---------")
                .clientSecret(passwordEncoder.encode("-----"))
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(false).build())
                .redirectUri("https://dev.inclub.world/authorized")
                .redirectUri("https://oidcdebugger.com/debug")
                .redirectUri("https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback")
                .redirectUri("https://oauthdebugger.com/debug")
                .redirectUri(gatewayServerPort + "/login/oauth2/code/backoffice-gateway")
                .redirectUri("http://gateway-dev.inclub:8090" + "/login/oauth2/code/backoffice-gateway")
                .redirectUri("http://gateway-dev.inclub:8090" + "/callback-local")
                .redirectUri("http://localhost:4200/auth-callback-local")
                .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:4200/profile/partner")
                .postLogoutRedirectUri(gatewayServerPort + "/logged-out")
                .postLogoutRedirectUri("http://gateway-dev.inclub:8090" + "/logged-out")
                .scope("read")
                .scope("write")
                .scope("internal")
                .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                .scope(OidcScopes.PROFILE)
                .scope(OidcScopes.EMAIL)
                .tokenSettings(TokenSettings.builder().accessTokenTimeToLive(Duration.ofMinutes(10)).build())
                .clientSettings(clientSettings())
                .build();

        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(oidcClient);
    }

    public void bindAuthenticationProvider(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth, AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientSettings clientSettings() {
        return ClientSettings.builder()
                .requireProofKey(true)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    OAuth2TokenCustomizer<JwtEncodingContext> tokenCustomizer() {
        return context -> {
            Authentication principal = context.getPrincipal();
            if (context.getTokenType()
                    .getValue()
                    .equals("id_token")) {
                context.getClaims()
                        .claim(
                                "Test",
                                "Test Id Token"
                        );
            }
            if (context.getTokenType()
                    .getValue()
                    .equals("access_token")) {
                context.getClaims()
                        .claim(
                                "Test",
                                "Test Access Token"
                        );
                Set<String> authorities = principal.getAuthorities()
                        .stream()
                        .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
                context.getClaims()
                        .claim(
                                "roles",
                                authorities
                        )
                        .claim(
                                "user",
                                principal.getName()
                        );
            }

        };
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings(@Value("${intechbo.oauth.issuer}") String issuer) {
        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder()
                .issuer(issuer)
                .build();
    }

This is my api of authenticate that I use to refresh my token:
@GetMapping("/authenticate")
    public Mono<TokenInfoResponseDto> login(@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("backoffice-gateway") OAuth2AuthorizedClient client,
                                            @AuthenticationPrincipal OidcUser user ) {

        String jwtToken = client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
        log.info("access token received from authorization server with value : {}", jwtToken);

        Mono<UserInfoResponseDto> userResponse = externalUserService.getUser(getAuth(jwtToken));

        log.info("user info received from authorization server with value : {}", userResponse);

        TokenInfoResponseDto tokenInfo = TokenInfoResponseDto.builder()
                .accessToken(client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue())
                .refreshToken(Objects.requireNonNull(client.getRefreshToken())
                        .getTokenValue()
                )
                .accessTokenExpireAt(client.getAccessToken().getExpiresAt())
                .authorities(extractAuthority(user))
                .accessTokenIssueAt(client.getAccessToken().getIssuedAt())
                .refreshTokenExpireAt(client.getRefreshToken().getExpiresAt())
                // Get id_token_hint
                .idTokenHint(user.getIdToken().getTokenValue())
                .build();

        return Mono.just(tokenInfo)
                .zipWith(userResponse)
                .map(tuple -> {
                    TokenInfoResponseDto tokenInfoResponseDto = tuple.getT1();
                    UserInfoResponseDto userInfoResponseDto = tuple.getT2();
                    tokenInfoResponseDto.setUserInfo(userInfoResponseDto);
                    return tokenInfoResponseDto;
                })
                .log();
    }

This is my securityConfig in my oauth2 Client:
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class ClientSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;

    @Value("${intechbo.server.gateway}")
    private String gatewayUrl;

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http,
                                                         ServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver resolver) {
        http
                .cors(ServerHttpSecurity.CorsSpec::disable)
                .csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable)
                .authorizeExchange(
                        exchanges -> exchanges
                                .pathMatchers(SecurityConstants.AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
                                .pathMatchers("/*.js", "/*.css", "/*.ico", "/*.jpg", "/*.png", "/*.html", "/*.svg").permitAll()
                                .pathMatchers(SecurityConstants.AUTH_ANGULAR_COMPILER_WHITELIST).permitAll()
                                .pathMatchers("/backoffice/home/**").permitAll()
                                .pathMatchers("/backoffice/home").permitAll()
                                .pathMatchers("/backoffice/authentication/logout-session").permitAll()
                                .pathMatchers("/backoffice/profile/**").authenticated()
                                .pathMatchers("/logged-out").permitAll()
                                .pathMatchers("/authenticate").authenticated()
                                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2Login(auth ->
                        auth.authorizationRequestResolver(resolver)
                                .authenticationSuccessHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler())
                )
                .oauth2Client(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .logout(
                        logout -> logout
                                .logoutSuccessHandler(oidcLogoutSuccessHandler())
                )
                .exceptionHandling(
                        exceptionHandlingSpec -> exceptionHandlingSpec
                                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())
                );
        return http.build();
    }

    private ServerAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler() {
        return new RedirectServerAuthenticationSuccessHandler("/backoffice/authentication/login");
    }

    private ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint() {
        RedirectServerAuthenticationEntryPoint webAuthenticationEntryPoint =
                new RedirectServerAuthenticationEntryPoint("/oauth2/authorization/backoffice-gateway");
        MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher textHtmlMatcher =
                new MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
        textHtmlMatcher.setUseEquals(true);

        return new DelegatingServerAuthenticationEntryPoint(
                new DelegatingServerAuthenticationEntryPoint.DelegateEntry(textHtmlMatcher, webAuthenticationEntryPoint));
    }


    private ServerLogoutSuccessHandler oidcLogoutSuccessHandler() {
        OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler oidcLogoutSuccessHandler =
                new OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler(this.clientRegistrationRepository);

        // Sets the location that the End-User's User Agent will be redirected to
        // after the logout has been performed at the Provider
        oidcLogoutSuccessHandler.setPostLogoutRedirectUri(gatewayUrl + "/logged-out");

        return oidcLogoutSuccessHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver pkceResolver(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository repo) {
        DefaultServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver resolver = new DefaultServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(repo);
        resolver.setAuthorizationRequestCustomizer(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestCustomizers.withPkce());
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ReactiveJwtDecoderFactory<ClientRegistration> idTokenDecoderFactory() {
        ReactiveOidcIdTokenDecoderFactory idTokenDecoderFactory = new ReactiveOidcIdTokenDecoderFactory();
        // RSA is the default algorithm, but we are using HS256
        idTokenDecoderFactory.setJwsAlgorithmResolver(clientRegistration -> SignatureAlgorithm.RS256);
        return idTokenDecoderFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient(ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2Client =
                new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
        oauth2Client.setDefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClient(true);
        return WebClient.builder()
                .filter(oauth2Client)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
                                                                         ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {
        ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
                ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                        .authorizationCode()
                        .refreshToken()
                        .clientCredentials()
                        .build();
        DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
                new DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository);
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);
        return authorizedClientManager;
    }

}

This is my application.yml for my oauth2Client:
logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
    org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping: DEBUG
    org:
      springframework:
        security: DEBUG
        session: DEBUG
        web: DEBUG


intechbo:
  server:
    gateway: ${GATEWAY_SERVER_PORT:http}
    oauth: ${OAUTH_SERVER_PORT:https}
    discover: ${DISCOVER_SERVER_PORT}
    webapp: ${WEBAPP_SERVER_PORT}

spring:
  application:
    name: bo-gateway-server
  session:
    redis:
      repository-type: default
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          backoffice-gateway:
            provider: spring
            client-id: client
            client-secret: ----
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: ${intechbo.server.gateway}/login/oauth2/code/backoffice-gateway
            scope: read,write,openid,profile
          backoffice-refresh:
            provider: spring
            client-id: backoffice-client
            client-secret: secret
            authorization-grant-type: refresh_token
            redirect-uri: ${intechbo.server.gateway}/login/oauth2/code/backoffice-gateway
            scope: read,write,openid,profile
        provider:
          spring:
            issuer-uri: ${intechbo.server.oauth}

  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Credentials Access-Control-Allow-Origin
#        - TokenRelay=
#        - SaveSession
      routes:

        -  id: account-service-route
           uri: http://localhost:8776
#           uri: --
           predicates:
             - Path=/api/v1/account/**
           filters:
             - TokenRelay=
             - SaveSession
             - name: Retry
               args:
                 retries: 5
                 methods: GET
                 backoff:
                   firstBackoff: 200ms
                   maxBackOff: 400ms
#             - name: CircuitBreaker
#               args:
#                 name: accountService
#                 fallbackUri: forward:/account-service-fallback
             - name: RequestRateLimiter
               args:
                 key-resolver: "#{@userKeyResolver}"
                 redis-rate-limiter.replenishRate: 2
                 redis-rate-limiter.burstCapacity: 2

        - id: membership-service-route
          uri: http://localhost:8776
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/v1/membership/**, /api/v1/pay/** , /api/v1/store/**
          filters:
            - TokenRelay=
            - SaveSession
            - name: Retry
              args:
                retries: 5
                methods: GET
                backoff:
                  firstBackoff: 50ms
                  maxBackOff: 400ms
            - name: RequestRateLimiter
              args:
                key-resolver: "#{@userKeyResolver}"
                redis-rate-limiter.replenishRate: 2
                redis-rate-limiter.burstCapacity: 2

        - id: treepointrange-service-route
          uri: http://localhost:8776
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/v1/three/**, /api/v1/placement/**
          filters:
            - TokenRelay=
            - SaveSession
            - name: RequestRateLimiter
              args:
                key-resolver: "#{@userKeyResolver}"
                redis-rate-limiter.replenishRate: 2
                redis-rate-limiter.burstCapacity: 2

        - id: wallet-service-route
          uri: http://localhost:8776
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/v1/wallet/**, /api/v1/wallettransaction/**, /api/v1/withdrawalrequest/**, /api/v1/tokenwallet/**, /api/v1/electronicpurse/**, /api/v1/accountbank/**
          filters:
            - TokenRelay=
            - SaveSession
            - name: RequestRateLimiter
              args:
                key-resolver: "#{@userKeyResolver}"
                redis-rate-limiter.replenishRate: 2
                redis-rate-limiter.burstCapacity: 2

#        - id: angular
#          uri: ${intechbo.server.webapp}
#          predicates:
#            - Path=/backoffice/**
#          filters:
##            - RewritePath=/backoffice(?<segment>/?.*), /$\\{segment}
#            - RewritePath=/backoffice(?<segment>/?.*), "/\\$\\{segment}"
        - id: angular
          uri: ${intechbo.server.webapp}
          predicates:
            - Path=/
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/, /backoffice
        - id: static
          uri: ${intechbo.server.webapp}
          predicates:
            - Path=/**
#          filters:
#            - SaveSession

  data:
    redis:
      port: ${REDIS_SERVER_PORT:6379}
      host: ${REDIS_SERVER_HOST:localhost}
      password: ${REDIS_SERVER_PASSWORD:}
      timeout: 5000
      lettuce:
        pool:
          max-idle: 9
          min-idle: 1
          max-active: 9
          max-wait: 5000

eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: ${intechbo.server.discover}
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true

server:
  port: 8090
  reactive:
    session:
      timeout: 710m
      cookie:
        name: INCLUB_SESSION
        max-age: 710m

resilience4j:
  circuitbreaker:
    configs:
      default:
        slidingWindowSize: 10
        slidingWindowType: COUNT_BASED
        permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState: 6
        failureRateThreshold: 50
        waitDurationInOpenState: 10s
        registerHealthIndicator: true
        automaticTransitionFromOpenToHalfOpenEnabled: true

    instances:
      accountService:
        baseConfig: default

  retry:
    instances:
      authorizationServer:
        maxAttempts: 3
        waitDuration: 2500ms
        enableExponentialBackoff: true
        exponentialBackoffMultiplier: 2

  timelimiter:
    configs:
      values:
        timeout-duration: 80s
    instances:
      offersTimeLimiter: # Unique name for TimeLimiter
        base-config: values

management:
  health:
    circuitbreakers:
      enabled: true
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always

Finally this is my config for my service in angular:
public authenticateTest(): void {
    // Quitando la subscripcion al observable para evitar fugas de memoria
    this.refreshSub?.unsubscribe();
    this.http.get<any>('/authenticate').subscribe({
      next: (data: IAuthentication) => {
        if (!!data.accessTokenExpireAt) {
          const now = Date.now();
          const expireAt = new Date(data.accessTokenExpireAt).getTime();
          var refreshToken = JSON.stringify(data.refreshToken);
          localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', refreshToken);
          console.log('Token will expire at', new Date(expireAt));
          const delay = expireAt - now - 30000; // Refresh 30 seconds before expiration
          console.log('Token will be refreshed in', delay, 'ms');
          if (delay > 2000) {
            this.refreshSub = interval(delay).subscribe(() => {
              console.log('Refreshing token...');
              this.authenticateTest();
            });
            console.log('Refresh interval set');
          }
        }
        this.redirectByProfile(data);
      },
      error: (error) => console.error(error)
    });
  }

Finally this is a short video error_logout about what is happening when the token is refresh and the logout stop working, if I logged out before the access token is expired it works but when the token is refreshed give me the error that I showing.

You really should take the time to read the article I linked in my answer, it might save you a lot of burden (at least for all that isn't related to Spring Authorization Server specificities: CSRF protection, post-login & post-logout URIs, ...)

Your issue with RP-Initiated Logout is due to an expired ID token in the BFF session.
The easiest option to force a token refresh on a BFF is probably using the TokenRelay filter: it uses the ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager which refreshes the tokens in the session (all of it, including the ID one) if the access token expired (or is close to). For that, send any request to a downstream resource server (it does not even need to be successful, it being routed with the TokenRelay should be enough).
This question is interesting because it raises an issue in Spring Security: the problem would not occur if the OidcClientInitiated(Server)LogoutSuccessHandler was using the (Reactive)OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager instead of the (Reactive)ClientRegistrationRepository (at least not if the refresh token is still valid).
In a Baeldung article that you should read carefully, I keep sessions alive by refreshing user data on a /me endpoint hosted on a resource server behind the gateway. This user data contains the access token expiration and the frontend schedules a call to the /me endpoint within the 60 seconds before. This call:

Resets the BFF session timeout.
Refreshes tokens on the BFF.
Provides the frontend with the exact same user info as what resource servers use for access control (including roles that can change from an access token to another if the user is updated on the authorization server): it is taken from the access token, and refreshed at the same time as it.

For the logout to work, the refresh must happen before the first of refresh-token and BFF session expirations. But I prefer using the access-token expiration because it should be configured to have the shortest lifespan and I like the idea that the frontend is permanently provided with the user authorities as parsed by the resource servers.
Important notes
Never disable CSRF protection in a filter chain with formLogin or oauth2Login: requests are authorized with sessions which are the vector for CSRF attacks.
I would not send tokens to the frontend (this makes it vulnerable in case of a compromised Javascript dependency) and, more importantly, I would not store refresh tokens in local storage (even if browsers built-in protection against XSS is thought to protect it). These tokens are stored in your BFF session already (where it is needed for the TokenRelay filter to do its job and the authorized client manager to refresh it) and are much safer there.

But I have this ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager in my ClientSecurityConfig as a @Primary, this api calls throught a webClient with getUser. This api is exposed in my authorization server that is :
@GetMapping("/users")
public ResponseEntity getAuthenticatedUser(Authentication authentication) {
UserResponseDto user = authUserService.getUserByUserName(authentication.getName());
    return ResponseEntity.ok(user);
}

I already tried your suggestion but it doesn't work, the error persists :c

I had misunderstood where your /authenticate stands. I fixed my answer. The tokens need to be refreshed in the BFF session, not in the authorization server one. It is the BFF building the redirection URI with the ID-token to the authorization server's end_session_endpoint. Also, the main session for the frontend is the BFF one, so it is this one that you want to keep alive. The authorization server session is used mainly for SSO: to authorize a new client instance, if the BFF session expire and you want to authorize a new one silently...
