Spring Security - Session changes during Auth flow with Auth0 - so cannot modify session attributes
I've connected my OAuth Client (a Spring Webflux server) to Auth 0. When the login initiation URI is hit in Spring, it saves the Auth Request to a session in Redis as an attribute. (This is the session maintained between Spring and the Public Client, Angular).
But then, when I reach the landing page of the Auth Server, a new session is created. Hence after I enter valid credentials, something calls the remove auth request method - but nothing gets removed and the auth flow fails because it tries to remove the Auth Request from the newly created session (when it was saved in the session before the new one got created).
Here are my server log messages - I land on the Auth0/Okta auth page, just after where it says "Session Created" below. (but at this point the auth request has already been saved to the session that existed before)

Here is my Auth Request Repository, but this itself is not the problem. It is the timing by which Save Request, and Remove Request are called.
@Repository
internal class RedisAuthorizationRequestRepository(
    private val redisSerialiserConfig: RedisSerialiserConfig
) : ServerAuthorizationRequestRepository<OAuth2AuthorizationRequest> {

    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RedisSecurityContextRepository::class.java)
    private val springAuthorizationRequestAttrName: String = "AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST"

    override fun saveAuthorizationRequest(
        authorizationRequest: OAuth2AuthorizationRequest?,
        exchange: ServerWebExchange
    ): Mono<Void> {
        logger.info("SAVING AUTHORIZATION REQUEST")

        return exchange.session
            .doOnNext { session ->
                println("AUTH REQUEST SESSION ID: " + session.id)
                if (authorizationRequest == null) {
                    session.attributes.remove(springAuthorizationRequestAttrName)
                    logger.info("Removed Authorization Request from WebSession: $session")
                } else {
                    session.attributes[springAuthorizationRequestAttrName] = authorizationRequest
                    logger.info("Saved Authorization Request $authorizationRequest in WebSession: $session")
                }
            }
            .then() }
    }

    override fun loadAuthorizationRequest(exchange: ServerWebExchange): Mono<OAuth2AuthorizationRequest?> {
        logger.info("LOADING AUTHORIZATION REQUEST")
        val state = getStateParameter(exchange) ?: return Mono.empty()
        return exchange.session
            .flatMap { session ->
                val authorizationRequest = getAuthorizationRequest(session)
                if (authorizationRequest != null && state == authorizationRequest.state) {
                    logger.info("Loading authorization request")
                    Mono.just(authorizationRequest)
                } else {
                    logger.warn("No authorization request found")
                    Mono.empty()
                }
            }
    }

    override fun removeAuthorizationRequest(exchange: ServerWebExchange): Mono<OAuth2AuthorizationRequest?> {
        logger.info("REMOVING AUTHORIZATION REQUEST")
        val requestPath = exchange.request.path
        println("REMOVING AUTHORIZATION REQUEST PATH: $requestPath")
        val state = getStateParameter(exchange) ?: return Mono.empty()
        return exchange.session
            .flatMap { session ->
                val authorizationRequest = getAuthorizationRequest(session)
                if (authorizationRequest != null && state == authorizationRequest.state) {
                    session.attributes.remove(this.springAuthorizationRequestAttrName)
                    logger.info("Removed authorization request")
                    Mono.just(authorizationRequest)
                } else {
                    logger.info("No authorization request found")
                    Mono.empty()
                }
            }
    }

    // Helper methods
    private fun getStateParameter(exchange: ServerWebExchange): String? {
        requireNotNull(exchange) { "exchange cannot be null" }
        return exchange.request.queryParams[OAuth2ParameterNames.STATE]?.firstOrNull()
    }

    private fun getAuthorizationRequest(session: WebSession): OAuth2AuthorizationRequest? {
        Assert.notNull(session, "session cannot be null")

        val authRequestAttr = session.getAttribute<Map<String, Any>>(springAuthorizationRequestAttrName)
        println("AUTH REQUEST: " + authRequestAttr)
        println("AUTH REQUEST SESSION ID: " + session.id)
        if (authRequestAttr != null) {
            // Deserialize from Map to SecurityContext
            val map = authRequestAttr as? Map<String, Any>
            try {
                val authorizationRequest = redisSerialiserConfig.redisObjectMapper()
                    .convertValue(map, OAuth2AuthorizationRequest::class.java)
                logger.info("Successfully deserialized Authorization Request: $authorizationRequest")
                return authorizationRequest
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                logger.error("Error deserializing Authorization Request: ${e.message}", e)
                return null
            }
        } else {
            logger.warn("No Authorization Request found in WebSession")
            return null
        }
    }

}

Update
I believe this is due to when I first try authenticating, the BFF Cookie is NOT sent when the browser goes to the callback URI
1st time round
Request URI
http://localhost:7080/bff/login/oauth2/code/auth0-server?code=_f_ypaflZK3tSDmXu1fdI2TQC5Fy8gSMuGYR4zs6jqwT6&state=9nE70pYtOgoWntdpwN2PR9ZKgX1P71s7Gs0CRj5AoDM%3D 

Cookie
is absent in request header
2nd time round
Request URI
http://localhost:7080/bff/login/oauth2/code/auth0-server?code=B2cmKAm619UWQl2oeKoyzpPAIyRWE2ERFBou_fVwsAFPR&state=ZQ1P5iY_XibEjoy7Ir1dlKr64g801nEnPoo7ybtBaZk%3D

Cookie
IS present in Request header
cookie:
BFF-SESSIONID=BFF-1724520718727-a2a4e1ef-4401-4bb4-9738-4195c21c614c;
Why might this be happening?
Here are the cookie settings:
BFF-SESSIONID=BFF-1724520718727-a2a4e1ef-4401-4bb4-9738-4195c21c614c; Max-Age=21600; Expires=Sat, 24 Aug 2024 23:31:58 GMT; Path=/; HTTPOnly; SameSite=Strict

Now, I understand it might be due to Path or some cross origin thing I don' get, but it doesn't explain why it doesn't get sent the first time I try to login but does work (does get sent) the second time.
